# how to get list of multipart file by doing unzip folder using spring mvc java

Tags: java, spring

I have zip folder having list of multipart file(`csv`,`xsl`..etc),
Now I want to store these files in database by using spring mvc.
first I want unzip  that folder and get **files in `ArrayList<Multipartfiles>`** and then store them into the database.

Comment: files in arraylist? Why? The main task is unzip file and store all files inside your DB right?

Comment: yes but after if  i want **particular file from DB**,then

Comment: you should store the file in some specific location and add an unique ID for the file stored, also add a column referencing the FK to the primary object

Comment: try something and then come up with a problem

Comment: ok that will also worked